# Merge filename.mp4.tmp with filename.mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, recording, wowza

How to merge a **abc.mp4.tmp** swap file with actual **abc.mp4** file. I was trying to recording a live event using Wowza Media server 3.6 and the recorded file was not muxed properly at final moment. The **abc.mp4.tmp** swap file was not merged with actual **abc.mp4** file. So could someone tell me how to merge the abc.mp4.tmp and abc.mp4 file and creates a new file and I can able to play with vlc

Here is the mediainfo of the files

```
[root@ip-ss-21-98-2 content]# mediainfo 03_03_2014_12_03_08.mp4
General
Complete name                            : 03_03_2014_12_03_08.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Adobe Flash
Codec ID                                 : f4v 
File size                                : 5.20 GiB


[root@ip-ss-21-98-2 content]# mediainfo 03_03_2014_12_03_08.mp4.tmp
General
Complete name                            : 03_03_2014_12_03_08.mp4.tmp
File size                                : 38.3 MiB
```

Comment: What information does `ffmpeg` show for `03_03_2014_12_03_08.mp4.tmp`? Please include the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i 03_03_2014_12_03_08.mp4.tmp`.

Comment: I haven't used FFMPEG for this recording. I'm using Wowza Media Server 3.6 version to record the live streams. All the live streams are being recording properly, but unfortunately this file (03_03_2014_12_03_08.mp4) was not merged well due to some reasons(might be network issue). Is there any option to merge it and create a new one using ffmpeg ? - Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: You need to include the console output that I requested.

Answer (score 0):

While recording is in progress, the `.mp4` file contains `ftyp` and `wide` atoms, followed by an `mdat` atom where video/audio data are appended. The `mdat` atom does not yet have its `size` or `type` fields set.

The `.mp4.tmp` file contains a Wowza-specific format used to store `stbl` (sample table) entries that can be appended to while recording. Each entry in this file has a 4-byte `type` field (`stsz`, `stts`, `stsc`, `stco` or `stss`), followed by a 4-byte `size` field, followed by `size` bytes of data (the bytes used by the `type`/`size` fields are not included in the value of the `size` field). This format is based on files I created with Wowza 4.1.2, and may change with new Wowza versions.

I also had a known good `.mp4` file created by Wowza from the same input source to use as a reference.

To create a working `.mp4` file, I set the `size` field of the `mdat` atom to the number of bytes remaining in the `.mp4` file and the `type` field to `mdat`, then appended a `moov` atom built from atoms in the known good file and the sample table entries in the `.mp4.tmp` file.

The sample table entries in the `.mp4.tmp` file don't indicate whether they apply to the video or audio tracks, so it took some guesswork based on average sample size, average samples per chunk, and order written into the `.mp4.tmp` file to determine how to map these entries to tracks. Since the recording was interrupted, not all of the sample tables indicated the same number of samples were present, so I truncated the longer ones.

[Apple's QuickTime File Format docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFPreface/qtffPreface.html) provided a good reference for the structure of the atoms I needed to recreate to get a working file.